# Create list based on HTML tags and plain text

Tags: python, split, python-re

I have this string:

```
data = "<div> <p> Hi Man, <strong> how are you</strong> today? </p> </div>"
```

**I would like to turn it in the following list:**

```
['', '<div>', ' ', '<p>', ' Hi Man, ', '<strong>', ' how are you', '</strong>', ' today? ', '</p>', ' ', '</div>', '']
```

At the moment I have this code:

```
import re

# initializing string
data = "<div> <p> Hi Man, <strong> how are you</strong> today? </p> </div>"
res2 = re.split(r'([<>])', data)
```

but the result for the HTML tags **is not as I described above**. Here my result:

```
['', '<', 'div', '>', ' ', '<', 'p', '>', ' Hi Man, ', '<', 'strong', '>', ' how are you', '<', '/strong', '>', ' today? ', '<', '/p', '>', ' ', '<', '/div', '>', '']
```

Could you help to fix it?
thanks in advance

Comment: Try `res2 = re.split(r'(<.*?>)', data)`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the order of the output does not matter, this would work.

```
import re
s = "<div> <p> Hi Man, <strong> how are you</strong> today? </p> </div>"
ptrn1 = re.compile(r"(<.*?>)")
ptrn2 = re.compile(r">([\w\d\s].*?)<")
tags = re.findall(ptrn1, s)
text = re.findall(ptrn2, s)
print(tags)
print(text)
print(tags+text)
```

Here's the output.

[image]